# Sharepoint Blog Font face and size

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, blog, rich-text

In the last few week I have had some users report that when they try to post to the Blog they are unable to change the font face or size of the text in the body, and it seems to be slowing hitting everyone, even I can't change the font from Verdana or the size from 8 now.

I have googled everything I can think of to find if anyone else has ever had this issue but even Google couldn't find something useful. anyone here ever see this issue?

is there any way to just change the default font size from 8?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using, and do you have any customizations in play via a masterpage, alternate css, etc..?

Comment: Sharepoint 2010 foundation. I made edits to the master page years ago, if I recall the edits I made were to delete the comments section and the RSS button. The only CSS added was for a count down clock but that was added after the issue started happening, and the "classes" are pretty specific to the clock.

Comment: The issue is odd if you click the dropdown for the font face the text will change while you are hovered over the font but once you click nothing happens.

I will also add that there is another blog in the site with the same edits and the countdown clock but no issues.

Comment: Have you tried using the developer toolbar (F12 in Chrome or IE) to look at the html being output, as well as looking to see if another style is overriding? I'd first suggest seeing if the font is getting applied in the html, and then determining if another class is just overriding it.